# How to replace before first occurrence of word in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, database, replace

I have `Select|_|8/1/2018|_|8/1/2018|_|Enter by Asset Type Here & Below|_|Enter Total Here|_||_|36|_||_||_|` in sql server DB column,

Want to till first occurrence `Select|_|` out put should be `8/1/2018|_|8/1/2018|_|Enter by Asset Type Here & Below|_|Enter Total Here|_||_|36|_||_||_|`

Thank you in advance

Comment: Format your examples for better understanding.

Answer (score 2):

For **your given sample data**, you can use `RIGHT` or `SUBSTRING` along with `CHARINDEX`.

```
declare @column varchar(4000) = 'Select||8/1/2018||8/1/2018||Enter by Asset Type Here & Below||Enter Total Here||||36|||||_|'

select 
   right(@column,len(@column) - charindex('|',@column) - 1)
   ,substring(@column,charindex('|',@column) + 2,len(@column))
```

Comment: @MaruthiReddySadhu then you should accept this answer.